# Manhwa where an ordinary person awakens as a mage, and remembers his past life

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

This manhwa is similar to *Solo Spell Caster*. It starts out with the main character as an ordinary person, and in this world there are people that have powers to fight monsters that I believe come through portals.

While driving, I believe his car gets wrecked by one of these monsters and a girl saves him, I believe she is very powerful. During this time, he awakens his skills as a mage, however that is not all; he also remembers that in his past life, he was a very powerful mage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[I Am the Sorcerer King](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-am-the-sorcerer-king)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> **Sunghoon Lee is nothing but a victim of a changing world, a powerless man in a land infested with beasts and magic. Monsters from another world invaded earth,** and they brought with them a sickness that pushes Sunghoon’s mother into an endless sleep. To pay off her medical bills, he braved a dangerous job as bait used by **powerful superhumans called Awakeners** to hunt monsters. **But when he found himself at death’s door, the image of his past life flashes through his mind. There, he found his truth: he is the reincarnation of the Sorcerer King!**

From [Baka-Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=154643):

> 10 years ago, the monster horde from the rift formed from space and time started attacking mankind. At the same time, people have started to awaken the power and began hunting the monsters for fame and money Lee SungHoon, in need of money because of his mother’s sickness, takes a dangerous job to help hunt those monsters four times a month by acting as a bait for the hunters. But one day, he is heavily injured by a monster and remembers his past life as a sorcerer-king ‘Huh? Did I just die?» ‘Wait, I was a Sorcerer King Kratraus in my previous life?’ With his past memories, SungHoon’s overpowered magic show begins.

Points that match:

- It's a manhwa (Korean comic).
- Ten years prior to the beginning og the story, monsters started emerging from portals in North Korea.
- Around the same time, a mysterious being, calling itself the 'Ahkasha Director', introduced itself to humanity, and randomly chose thousands of people to be given upgradeable, stat-based powers, that would allow them to fight and kill the monsters, like characters in a [JRPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Eastern_role-playing_video_games) video game. These people became known as Awakened, and some gained celebrity status.
- The main character, Lee Sunghoon, is initially a regular person in modern Korea, but after being injured, remembers a previous life where he was a powerful sorcerer named Kuratauras, who died fighting a giant black dragon named Akaluman, and cast a reincarnation spell in his dying moments. Upon regaining these memories, he also gains stat-based powers like an Awakened, but starts out at a low level with the job class of 'Apprentice Magician'.
- In chapter 5, Sunghoon meets a powerful, red-haired woman he recognises as 'Sung Yaerim', one of the highest level Awakened in the nation.

Points that don't match:

- Sunghoon is injured when a gas station explodes just as he was riding his *scooter* (not car) away from it.
- When Sunghoon first encounters Sung Yaerim, she doesn't save him. Rather, she falls from the sky, injured from fighting a monster, and he uses magic to heal her, after which she resumes her battle with the monster.